# augmenting namespace in declaration file in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add commands onto the the Cypress namespace.  I have created a `commands.d.ts` file:

import { ElementContext, RunOptions } from 'axe-core';
import { Result } from 'axe-core';

```
export type ViolationCallback = (violations: Result[]) => void;

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
    checkA11yAndReportViolations(context?: ElementContext, options?: RunOptions): void;
    checkA11yLocal(context?: ElementContext, options?: RunOptions, violationCallback?: ViolationCallback): void;
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es6",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "integration/**/*.ts",
    "support/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/cypress"
  ]
}
```

My commands.d.ts file is in the `support` folder referenced in the includes above but when I try and call the function in `integration/spec.ts`:

```
cy.checkA11yAndReportViolations();
```

tsc complains:

> Property 'checkA11yAndReportViolations' does not exist on type
>   'Chainable'.

Answer (score 0):

Works ok for me, maybe you forgot to implement the interface

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es6",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "integration/**/*.ts",
    "support/*.ts",
    "../node_modules/cypress"
  ]
}
```

integration/spec.ts

```
import { Cypress } from '../support/commands'

export class Demo implements Cypress.Chainable {
  checkA11yAndReportViolations () {
    console.log('CALLED checkA11yAndReportViolations')
  }
  checkA11yLocal () {
    console.log('CALLED checkA11yLocal')
  }
}
```

support/commands.d.ts

```
import { ElementContext, RunOptions } from 'axe-core';
import { Result } from 'axe-core';

export type ViolationCallback = (violations: Result[]) => void;

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
    checkA11yAndReportViolations(context?: ElementContext, options?: RunOptions): void;
    checkA11yLocal(context?: ElementContext, options?: RunOptions, violationCallback?: ViolationCallback): void;
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import { Demo } from './integration/spec'

const d = new Demo()

d.checkA11yAndReportViolations()
```

Result

```
~/Documents/Dev/github/demo
❯ ts-node ./index.ts
CALLED checkA11yAndReportViolations
```

Comment: Cypress works a bit weirdly using it's `Cypress.Commands.add("checkA11yAndReportViolations"` type interface for adding functions to the namespace.

I wrapped it the declaration in `declare global {` and now tsc seems happy